# Is there a way to create WebIDL bindings for C++ templated types?

Tags: c++, templates, emscripten, webidl

Let's say in C++ i have a function with the following signature:

```
A<B> getTemplatedClassInstance();
```

where A & B are some classes. I am then trying to generate WebIDl bindings for use in an emscripten build to use the C++ code from Javascript. I have a working bindings file with various other classes, enums, etc that can be bound and accessed from JS, but I'm at a loss for how to represent templated types (class A, in the above example). I have tried various combinations of WebIDL binding declarations like:

```
interface A {};
interface A<> {};
interface A<B> {};

interface C {
A<B> getTemplatedClassInstance();
};

interface C {
A getTemplatedClassInstance();
};
```

But any use of angle brackets '<>' generates a syntax error from the webidl_binder.py script (included with the emscripten sdk) used to build it, and if I leave the declaration and uses of A as untemplated, the bindings file builds, but the final emscripten compilation (emcc ...) of the bindings with the C++ library fails in the bindings cpp file with:

> error: use of class template requires template
>   arguments

which makes sense. Oddly the WebIDL documentation doesn't mention template types at all. I scoured the web and found a [single reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/emscripten-discuss/qwp379g6E0Q) to binding specific template instantiations with "Embind", but nothing regarding WebIDL.

Comment: I'm dealing with the same issue here. I'm thinking of create a custom class that extends the templated class but with a concrete type ie class FooBar: Foo<Bar> and use that in the webidl definition. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: @Zubzub I had forgotten to come back and resolve this question, but I found a solution. You can just typedef the template types. For example, I created a separate template_typedefs.h file that has lines like:
`typedef A<B> class_A_of_B`,
and then `include` that file in the build and you can freely use 'class_A_of_B' as the concrete type in the idl file. Hope that helps.

Comment: If you'd like to use `std::vector`, do you have to redefine it in the `.idl` for each type?